# Ground data(real data) for precipitation(rainfall/mm) of India

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I need recent 10-15 years datasets of precipitation(rainfall/mm) for India. I have obtained many projection datasets but I need real datasets.

Requirements:

1. Real Datasets
2. datasets of 2005-2020
3. 1 degree * 1 degree
4. 3 hourly or 6 hourly datasets
5. India datasets

Can anyone can suggest sources for the above?